# Как сделать обычный шрифт ttf или otf жирным, курсивом или жирным курсивом php

Tags: php, ttf, otf

Из за требований хешкода, весь вопрос в заголовке:

Как сделать обычный шрифт ttf или otf жирным, курсивом или жирным курсивом php?

Понятно, вот дополнение: На картинке вывести текст.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужны соответствующие шрифты. Как правило для bold в конце названия шрифта пишется b. Например Arialb.ttf

Comment: Согласен Но некоторые приложения как то обходят это или может где то у себя держат оригиналы других! К примеру: я добавил шрифт новый (курсив только), а в ворде появился и жирный и обычный и жирный курсив. Инте отрубал, пробовал - все равно появляются.

Answer (score 0):

хм как я понял обычный текст сделать жирным или курсивом в php, то
echo "< b>Ваш текст< /b>";
так же и с курсивом только вместо b вставляете i
P.S. убери пробелы